# How do I register my application locally created with one I created in Azure Active Directory?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-powershell, azure-keyvault

I am following directions here for learning the AzureKeyVault config settings

> ## Key Vault Configuration Provider sample application (ASP.NET Core 2.x)
>
> This sample illustrates the use of the Azure Key Vault Configuration
>   Provider for ASP.NET Core 2.x. For the ASP.NET Core 1.x sample, see
>   [Key Vault Configuration Provider sample application (ASP.NET Core
>   1.x)](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/security/key-vault-configuration/samples/basic-sample/1.x).
>
> For more information on how the sample works, see the Azure Key Vault
>   configuration provider topic.
>
> ### Using the sample
>
> 1. Create a key vault and set up Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) for the application following the guidance in [Get started with Azure Key
>      Vault](https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/key-vault-get-started/).
>
>    - Add secrets to the key vault using the [AzureRM Key Vault PowerShell Module](/powershell/module/azurerm.keyvault) available from the
>        [PowerShell
>        Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureRM.KeyVault),
>        the [Azure Key Vault REST API](/rest/api/keyvault/), or the [Azure
>        Portal](https://portal.azure.com/). Secrets are created as either
>        *Manual* or *Certificate* secrets. *Certificate* secrets are certificates for use by apps and services but are not supported by the
>        configuration provider. You should use the *Manual* option to create
>        name-value pair secrets for use with the configuration provider.
>
>      - Simple secrets are created as name-value pairs. Azure Key Vault secret names are limited to alphanumeric characters and dashes.
>      - Hierarchical values (configuration sections) use `--` (two dashes) as a separator in the sample. Colons, which are normally used
>          to delimit a section from a subkey in ASP.NET Core
>          configuration, aren't allowed
>          in secret names. Therefore, two dashes are used and swapped for a
>          colon when the secrets are loaded into the app's configuration.
>      - Create two *Manual* secrets with the following name-value pairs. The first secret is a simple name and value, and the second
>          secret creates a secret value with a section and subkey in the secret
>          name:
>
>        - `SecretName`: `secret_value_1`
>        - `Section--SecretName`: `secret_value_2`
>    - **Register the sample app with Azure Active Directory.**
>    - **Authorize the app to
>        access the key vault. When you use the
>        `Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy` PowerShell cmdlet to authorize the
>        app to access the key vault, provide `List` and `Get` access to
>        secrets with `-PermissionsToSecrets list,get`.**
> 2. Update the app's *appsettings.json* file with the values of `Vault`, `ClientId`, and `ClientSecret`.
> 3. Run the sample app, which obtains its configuration values from `IConfigurationRoot` with the same name as the secret name.    *
>      Non-hierarchical values: The value for `SecretName` is obtained with
>      `config["SecretName"]`.    * Hierarchical values (sections): Use `:`
>      (colon) notation or the `GetSection` extension method. Use either of
>      these approaches to obtain the configuration value:
>
>    - `config["Section:SecretName"]`
>    - `config.GetSection("Section")["SecretName"]`

Okay so I have copied the name of my application into Azure Active Directory as an 'Enterprise Application'.  And I have added 'Access policies' for 'get' and 'list' in Azure for my ADD object I just created.  Yet I get this error in the program when attempting to start the application:

```
Exception: {"error":"unauthorized_client","error_description":"AADSTS70001: 
Application with identifier '(guid)' was not found in the directory ...(continues)
```

**Update 8-4-18**
Okay I found out that Azure uses the 'ClientId' and 'ClientSecret' in the local appsettings.json to connect to what Azure registers in this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#log-in-as-the-application

1. I get the clientId in appsettings.json from the applicationId on ADD I create with ADD>App Registrations>New
2. I click settings in ADD on the app I just created and create a key with an expiration to store as ClientSecret in appsettings.json.
3. I change my 'Vault' in appsettings to my named vault.
4. I run the powershell above to give access or else do it in ADD.

So now I am getting a simpler error:

```
'Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Models.KeyVaultErrorException: 'Access denied''
```

I have tried running as Administrator in Visual Studio.  I went under Subscriptions in Azure>Access Control>(IAM)>set my new apps to Reader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ultimate problem for me became that running 'Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy' was not needed and for whatever reason it was easier to just ignore it and follow this subsection: https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/key-vault-get-started/#authorize

I kept trying to set up Object Id and Keys and really I had just overlooked a section mentioning a 'ServerPrincipalName'

They set one commandlet for keys

```
Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName '<vaultName>' -ServicePrincipalName <ApplicationIdGuid> -PermissionsToKeys decrypt,sign
```

They set one commandlet for secrets

```
Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName '<vaultName>' -ServicePrincipalName <ApplicationIdGuid> -PermissionsToSecrets Get, List
```

But I decided to follow the immediate proceeding section on doing it all in the Portal.  The key take away for me was that the instructions were not wrong.  Just vague when it says: "Register a sample app" then "Authorize the App".  Really they should be saying

> Register a sample app (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-get-started#register)
>   Authorize the app with Key Vault (https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/key-vault-get-started/#authorize)

Ultimately all the information is there it was just confusing if you happen to already have a vault and an application and don't understand the prerequisite is that really you need to have a 1. A Vault, 2. An ADD Web Application, 3. Associate permissions for 2 in 1.

Answer (score 2):

So the reason your powershell is failing is because you are trying to assign a `User Principal` - a user - when actually you want a `Service Principal`.

I can’t see your C# to support more there than saying when you use the SDK to log in as the Service Principal you use the application id of the Application/Service Principal (its the same id).

The service principal acts like a user in the local directory but you log in as the application.

---

Edit:

I looked at the example you posted and ran it myself and had very similar problems. However I have got it working. Here's the steps:

### Creating the Application

1. Create the Registered Application. I do this through the Azure Portal so
   a Service Principal is created automatically. Make a note of the `ApplicationId`.
2. Generate a key credential on the created application and make a note of it.
3. In the Application click on the link to the `Managed app in local directory`. This is the Service Principal, make a note of the `ObjectId`

### Creating the Key Vault

1. Create KeyVault - I used PowerShell to do this. `New-AzureRmKeyVault`
2. Apply the Service Principal to the Key Vault.

   ```
   Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName <vault> -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName> -ObjectId <Object Id of the Created Service Principal> -PermissionsToSecrets Get,List
   ```

### Running the Sample App

In your application settings follow this format:

```
{
  "Vault": <the name of your vault>,
  "ClientId": <ApplicationId of the Registered Application>,
  "ClientSecret": <Credential generated from the Registered Application>
}
```

This worked for me and allowed me to run the sample and retrieve the secrets from the vault.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you use 'Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy' with the proper switch?  I am not seeing how to do what you are saying but yeah I get what you mean.

Comment: Not a problem this is taken from [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.keyvault/set-azurermkeyvaultaccesspolicy?view=azurermps-6.6.0#examples). 

`Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName 'Contoso03Vault' -ObjectId 34595082-9346-41b6-8d6b-295a2808b8db -PermissionsToSecrets Get,Set`. 

Where ObjectId is the ObjectId of your Enterprise Application you want to grant access to the keyvault.

Comment: Okay that works but I am confused as it still blows up on the 'var keyVaultConfig = keyVaultConfigBuilder.Build();' in the program.cs of the example with the same as above.  This object Id I was running the command from the local directory of the application LOCALLY point to the REMOTE application Object Id I set up in ADD.  Is there a way to set an Object Id locally that I should use?  I am just confused because ADD has tons of GUIDS everywhere.

Comment: So the GUID you need is the application ID of the application in your local directory. You need to create a key on this application and that’s your client secret. These need to go in the `client_id` and `client_secret` fields in the `appsettings.json` respectively.

Comment: Okay you lost me there as what matches to what.  Am I putting in the ADD ApplicationId in my LOCAL appsettings.json under the key pair 'ApplicationId' and then the 'ClientSecret' is just whatever GUID I want or does that match up to something?

Comment: Yes to the application id. No to the client secret [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#get-application-id-and-authentication-key) shows you how to get the client secret. The client secret is a key you generate on the AAD application.

Comment: Aha.  I think that is where I was confused.  So I just want to reiterate: 1. I get the clientId in appsettings.json from the applicationId on ADD.  2. I click settings in ADD on the app I just created and create a key with an expiration to store as ClientSecret in appsettings.json.  3. I change my 'Vault' in appsettings to my named vault.  4. I run the powershell above to give access.  I am making progress but now instead of unauthorized it gives a much simpler 'Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Models.KeyVaultErrorException: 'Access denied''

Comment: I am going away probably for a day or so but would love to finally get this working.  Thanks so much for the help thus far.  If you can get me through it I would definitely appreciate it.

Comment: Ok so you’re logged in now as your application user. The problem with the access denied will be related to your access policy so perhaps the call your doing your application user doesn’t have access to

Comment: But shouldn't it be a proxy at this point for an application and not the user?

Comment: Yes sorry my terminology was a little off there by application use I mean AAD application.

Comment: I updated my example question to be simpler and I also set up AIM levels.  I am not certain what it could be at this point.  I will keep looking to tutorials of what it could be.  I will be away for a day or two but am curious to try other things later.

Comment: Sorry I think I’ve advised you wrong on this one!! Use the application id of your AAD application to register an access policy using the cmdlet I gave you earlier but replace the objectid with the objectid of the AAD application and not the enterprise application.

Comment: I did that but it was still not working.  I am going to start over from scratch with wiping out all the references to all ADD applications and permissions to the Azure Key Vault.  If that doesn't work I will try some more things and potentially start a bounty on this question.

Comment: I've stopped trying to advise you from memory and run the application myself. I've edited my answer to show you how I got it working. Let me know how you get on!

Comment: You are leaving out a huge portion of what I found was actually wrong.  But your level of detail was detailed and helpful, so I thank you and will give you a positive.

Comment: Oh? What was it you found was wrong? This worked for me

Comment: It had to do with what permissions you set doing authorization of the KeyVault when selecting items.  The commandlet method works but it was not setting the 'get, list' of 'secrets' correctly for whatever reason.  This time I just started fresh and did everything from the portal and ignored the powershell completely.

Comment: Oh yeah I've just spotted my Powershell line doesn't apply that! Sorry!! Glad it's sorted!! I'll update and that should provide a fully working solution